# Не импортируется модуль pysqlcipher3

Tags: python, pip, модули, venv, pysqlcipher3

Устанавливаю через `pip`, через нужное виртуальное окружение, нужные зависимости вроде `wheel`, `setuptools` так же на месте.
Лог установки:

```
Collecting pysqlcipher3
  Using cached pysqlcipher3-1.2.0.tar.gz (102 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pysqlcipher3
  Building wheel for pysqlcipher3 (setup.py) ... done
  WARNING: Legacy build of wheel for 'pysqlcipher3' created no files.
  Command arguments: 'e:\type49\python\test_projects\jsui\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c '
  exec(compile('"'"''"'"''"'"'
  # This is <pip-setuptools-caller> -- a caller that pip uses to run setup.py
  #
  # - It imports setuptools before invoking setup.py, to enable projects that directly
  #   import from `distutils.core` to work with newer packaging standards.
  # - It provides a clear error message when setuptools is not installed.
  # - It sets `sys.argv[0]` to the underlying `setup.py`, when invoking `setup.py` so
  #   setuptools doesn'"'"'t think the script is `-c`. This avoids the following warning:
  #     manifest_maker: standard file '"'"'-c'"'"' not found".
  # - It generates a shim setup.py, for handling setup.cfg-only projects.
  import os, sys, tokenize
  
  try:
      import setuptools
  except ImportError as error:
      print(
          "ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in "
          "the build environment.",
          file=sys.stderr,
      )
      sys.exit(1)
  
  __file__ = %r
  sys.argv[0] = __file__
  
  if os.path.exists(__file__):
      filename = __file__
      with tokenize.open(__file__) as f:
          setup_py_code = f.read()
  else:
      filename = "<auto-generated setuptools caller>"
      setup_py_code = "from setuptools import setup; setup()"
  
  exec(compile(setup_py_code, filename, "exec"))
  '"'"''"'"''"'"' % ('"'"'C:\\Users\\type49\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-epb8miub\\pysqlcipher3_bd77ad630ae24fe59a0009c808e84fc9\\setup.py'"'"',), "<
pip-setuptools-caller>", "exec"))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\type49\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-hpji913l'
  Command output: [use --verbose to show]
  Running setup.py clean for pysqlcipher3
Failed to build pysqlcipher3
Installing collected packages: pysqlcipher3
  Running setup.py install for pysqlcipher3 ... done
Successfully installed pysqlcipher3
```

Пробовал устанавливать с флагами `--no-cache-dir` и `--no-binary :all:`, результат тот же - модуля нет ни в пиплисте, ни в пипфризе.